# Large parse tree for simple C expression

Tags: antlr4

I'm using the C grammar here: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/c to parse the expression `int a2 = 5;`. ANTLR version is 4.3.

The "5" here matches a very large chain of rules: `initializer->assignmentExpression->conditionalExpression->logicalOrExpression->logicalAndExpression->`... around 10 more `-> primaryExpression->5`.

While the parsing is correct eventually, this seems like a bug in the grammar. Can someone suggest fixes or clarifications?

[image: Image of parse tree]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is no bug. The lower down the tree simply means the higher the precedence of the operator(s).

## EDIT

The fact that the rules are chained like that is probably because Terence wrote the grammar from the C11 spec (it says so in the comments of the grammar). And in the official specs, the rules are probably written like that. You could rewrite the grammar in a more compact way however. ANTLR4 allows for direct recursive rules, making the rules:

```
expr
 : add
 ;

add
 : mult (('+'|'-') mult)*
 ;

mult
 : unary (('*'|'/') unary)*
 ;

unary
 : '-' atom
 | atom
 ;

atom
 : '(' expr ')'
 | NUMBER
 ;
```

equivalent to the following single (ANTLR4) rule:

```
expr
 : '-' expr
 | expr ('*'|'/') expr // higher precedence than rules starting with `expr` defined below
 | expr ('+'|'-') expr
 | '(' expr ')'
 | NUMBER
 ;
```

Comment: I had another doubt: the grammar interprets `int a1;` as `declarationSpecfiers`, i.e., the tokens `int` and `a1` are interpreted as `declarationSpecifier`. I expect `a1` to be interpreted as a part of `initDeclaratorList`. I fixed this by changing the `declaration` rule to use `initDeclarationList` instead of `initDeclarationList?`. Is this OK or does this break something else?

Comment: @AnujKalia, hmm, don't know. You could raise an issue/question on the repository's tracker: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/issues

Answer (score 0):

The grammar could possibly be designed different though, resulting in a less deep result.

See https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4#L497 for an example. This combines many levels on precedence in one rule. I'm not sure if a similar rule could be created (and would be readable) for `C` but it might be possible.

This kind of rule (including direct left recursion) was not available in previous versions of Antlr4 so the `C` grammar might have been created in times when this kind of rule would not be available.

Comment: If you put all the different operations into one rule you cannot control operator precedence (not to mention the readability of the grammar).

Comment: @MikeLischke: But it seems to work in the mentioned Java grammar (I modified it for my own grammar, too). Readability may suffer as I mentioned.

Comment: @MikeLischke, yes you can: the following is a valid ANTLR4 rule where `*` and `/` have a higher precedence than `+` and `-` because they're defined first: `e : e ('*'|'/') e | e ('+'|'-') e | INT;`

Comment: @MikeLischke It may even be more readable since all is kept in one place. At least the Java expression rule seems readable to me. But as I said that may not hold true for the C rule. But I'm sure, at least some rules could be combined without affecting readability, maybe even enhancing it.